# customizing wxpython dialog

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

How would I go about changing an existing WXPython dialog? For example, say I want to add a "search subdirectories" checkbox to the `wx.dirDialog`.
I know I'd need to subclass it, but how would I add a control (like a text box or check box) while leaving existing functionality intact?

Comment: We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This should be self explanatory:

```
class SubclassDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Subclass', size=(150, 100))
        self.Centre()
        okButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK", pos=(25, 40))
        okButton.SetDefault()
        textbox = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(20,15))
```